# Image Magick and Ghostscript

Tags: linux, centos, imagemagick, ghostscript

I mainly do web design but I host a few client sites on a Centos 5 VPS.

A new client has asked me to host their site and I've been given the following configuration requirement:

```
Apache 2.2.3 
PHP 5.2.17 
MySQL 5.0.77 
Image Magick 6.5.1-0 (not as an Apache module) 
Ghostscript 8.7
```

Checking php_info() I have:

```
Apache 2.2.3
PHP 5.2.14
MySQL 5.0.90
```

I don't have IM or GS listed.

I expect that my versions of PHP and MySQL are similar enough to work, but how do I get my server set up to work with this client's site as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current ImageMagick in the C5 repositories is ImageMagick-6.2.8.0-12.el5, which might be worryingly down-rev for you; `yum list ImageMagick ghostscript` to see those.

If the client is hard-and-fast about their minimum versions, you might be better off with C6 (apache 2.2.15, php 5.3.3, mysql 5.1.52, ImageMagick 6.5.4, ghostscript 8.70).  If they want those exact versions, you're in for a lot of compilation fun.

Comment: Thank you.  It'll only be too down-rev for me if the site doesn't work, so I'll check out the differences.

Comment: Upgrading to C6 will impact all my sites, so I don't really fancy that today - I need a strong coffee and a clear diary to take that on!

Answer (score 0):

They are in separate packages. In my Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache search ghost | grep php
php5-ps - ps module for PHP 5

$ apt-cache search magick | grep php
php5-imagick - ImageMagick module for php5
```